# How do you create a lable with two words in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, label

I would like to have that out in two words

Answer (score 2):

Specify the field name by joining the two word with with `_`; it will be interpreted as two separate words in the label.

Eg:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />

  <%= f.label :last_name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

will produce

```
<form action="/people" class="new_person" id="new_person" method="post">
  <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="NrOp5bsjoLRuK8IW5+dQEYjKGUJDe7TQoZVvq95Wteg=" />
  <label for="person_first_name">First name</label>:
  <input id="person_first_name" name="person[first_name]" type="text" /><br />

  <label for="person_last_name">Last name</label>:
  <input id="person_last_name" name="person[last_name]" type="text" /><br />

  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Person" />
</form>
```

Note how `first_name` and `last_name` becomes `First name` and `Last name` in the label.